# query related to latches

Tags: digital-logic, clock

I had two doubts about the working of an s-r latch. One is, when we apply a clock signal along with the s and r inputs to the gates, how do we administer the time after which the clock signal changes again. And when the latch is set where does the electronic pulse get stored? Does it get stored in a capacitor? And if it does then how does the capacitor get discharged when the latch is reset?

Comment: Clock signals don't get applied to the S or R inputs.

Comment: I seems you did not: you still mention a clock signal. An S-R latch has just the two inputs S and R. Hence its name :)

Comment: I am talking about the sr latch which has s, clock,q' as inputs to one nand gate and r,  clock, q as inputs to another nand gate. Maybe I had to call it a flip flop, right?

Answer (score 1):

It gets stored in the stable state of a gate feed back loop.

The RS latch is made out of two NAND or NOR gates. There are two feed back wires and each state set and reset correspond to one of them being high with the other being low.

There are no capacitors.

Answer (score 0):

1. SR Latch have only 2 inputs 'S' and 'R'. Then where you will apply the clock signal, as there are only 2 inputs. I think you are thinking of Applying clock signal to one of the inputs, then the output depends on the other input and the time at which clock change  depends on the time period and duty cycle of the clock which you are giving
2. As said by Dan, there were no capacitors storing the charge in a latch, because of the combinational feedback loop present it reaches a stable output and remain there until and unless you change the inputs

Comment: But in an sr flip flop(which has a clock, s and r, and q and q' as inputs to the nand gates) the value of q and q' would change when the clock is set to zero, right? So wouldn't a feedback network fail there?

Comment: Because the whole point of this is to store a bit.

Comment: When we make clock =0 in FF, then the FF retains the same o/p present before making clk=0. this is what storing a bit of info. in FF mean